# I want to show or fetch data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show or fetch teacher's name but it always fetch only the teacher's id, Thanks for your help.

This is my code:

```
 <?php
     include('../dbcon.php');

     $query=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from `teacher_class`");
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        ?>
        <tr>

         <td><?php echo $row['class_id']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['school_year']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['teacher_id']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['subject_id']; ?></td>
```

Here is Teacher Class Table on Data base
[image: Teacher Class Table on Data base]

Here, the Teacher table
[image: Teacher table on Data base]

And the Assign Teacher Table
[Assign Teacher Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqQYI.png)

Comment: Can you post all code of table?

Comment: Where do you want to show your teacher's name? I don't see a place to do this

Comment: instead of teacher id , I want to show teachers name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying values from multiple tables, you need to join the tables and then only you can display them.

Do read about https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp to get an idea of SQL JOINS.

Try the below code.

```
$query=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM 'teacher' AS teacher INNER JOIN teacher_class ON teacher.teacher_id = teacher_class.teacher_id");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['class_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['school_year']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['mname'].' '.$row['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['subject_id']; ?></td>
```

Comment: i want to fetch the class name not the class_id

Comment: because it always show class id on my table

Comment: instead of teachers id I want to fetch teachers name

Comment: which table has the class name? I dont see class_name from the screenshots

Answer (score -1):

Here is the query as you want

```
SELECT tc.teacher_id, t.teacher_name, tc.subject_id FROM teacher_class AS tc LEFT JOIN teacher ON t.teacher_id = tc.teacher_id
```